transferring files to box.net causes potential denial of service warning from GCP
I need to transfer fairly large files that are located on Box.net to/from my VM.  I thought this would be simple, but when I do the transfer (through the Box.net API), I consistently get warnings from GCP automated monitoring saying my account might be violating the GCP terms of service and potentially doing a denial of service attack. I'm just transferring files.
I've responded each time with an appeal, but sometimes GCP support doesn't respond and just terminates the VM.  This is always when I am transferring files (which I need to do).  I see in the documentation, I can go through google drive as an alternative.  Another option seems to be to rate limit my interface.  Anyone know a reasonable rate to use that won't keep tripping the analysis tool? 10mbit seems pretty slow, but I'm really tired of trying to argue this isn't a denial of service attack.
sudo tc qdisc change dev ens5 root tbf rate 10mbit burst 32kbit latency 400ms
Is there some other way to inform GCP that I'm about to do a transfer so that it's clear that I'm doing it and it isn't nafarious.  It's quite annoying.
